# Power flicked after changing my outlets

Tags: receptacle

I am really stumped. My husband and I own a double wide. Yesterday we changed out a double light switch that had a dimmer to just a double switch.
We had no issues at all until today. More than 24hrs later.
We were attempting to put in 2 pot lights off 1 of the switches and pulled the wire down and a few minutes later some of the lights in our home started flickering.
They flickered 2x and less than 45 seconds later they flickered again. My husband moved that hanging wire again and then the breaker tripped.
Now we only have 1 outlet in our Florida room that is working from that breaker. Everything else is dead.
We used our non-contact voltage tester and we have no power running to that double switch, master bathroom outlet, front carport outlet or the master bathroom outlets.
Any advise or guidance on what could be happening would be awesome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Flickering can be from a short or open but the breaker tripping is a short (overload).

I had had an apprentice wire up some new motion lights they worked for a day and died,

he did not want to try to troubleshoot but the hot had broke loose and shorted on the metal box.

It can happen go back to each box and check the wires a wire can pull out of a wire nut or break off and not be one you touched but in a group that was moved (it happens).

With the breaker tripping there will probably be evidence of a short of some type.

Comment: Giving it a try right now. Thank you so much

Comment: Now it is working but I have not changed anything yet. I have to have a short or something

Comment: The wires in a box probably have a skinned wire touching another wire like a ground or the side of a metal box, I had that happen to me at the hospital just last week when stuffing wires back into a metal box.

Comment: @SallyMead  If you did not find the problem with the first pass, recheck again, it can be a small nick in the wire covering that is hard to find.

Comment: So we took it out of the wall, checked it over THOROUGHLY well at least we thought. Hooked it back up, pushed it back in the plastic drywall box. Lights and plugs worked, pushed in the screws to attach switches to box, still worked, got to the 2nd switch (the one that game me problems the first go round) and everything worked until it got a centimeter from it being all the way in and boom “the light and outlets” go back off!!! Uggghhh

Comment: Sounds like you have found it!!! With the power off pull it back out looking for burn marks or small holes in the insulation, could be a ground wire hitting a screw or a skinned wire touching the bare ground, some electrical tape can fix a skinned wire, look around and I am sure you will find it, repair and put it back together, you may have saved a service call and done your own updates ,,, stressful at times but it gets easier and you found a tough one hood job!

Comment: Yes! Found it… THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR BEING PATIENT WITH THIS FRUSTRATING renovation.